# How to get checkbox value from a TGroupBox in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, checkbox

I have a groupbox and three check boxes in a form. And I want to get the user selected values in an array of values and If he doesn't selects one then the default enabled checkbox value needs to be selected into an array.

```
var selectedValues:String;
selectedValues:= getSelectedCheckboxValue(); //Here I want to pass the  selected values to store it into an array
function getSelectedCheckboxValue(): string;
begin
 var retArr:array[1..3] of string;
 return retArr;
end;
```

Is my approach correct? Or Is there an other way to do it.

Comment: Your code does not compile, nor does it make sense. You need to step back a little, think harder about your problem, and ask a clearer question.

Comment: If your function result is *string* you cannot return a type *array[1..3] of string*. If you absolutely want to return a string (we don't know if that is smart in your context; and besides, what is in the string ('0' and '1')?), why not just append characters to result when you are investigating the checkboxes?

Comment: what is supposed to be `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive I've guessed what you are asking about

Try this function:

```
function GetSelectedCheckboxValue(CheckListBox: TCheckListBox): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result := '';

  for i := 0 to CheckListBox.Count - 1 do
    if CheckListBox.Checked[i] then
      Result := Result + CheckListBox.Items[i] + ',';


  System.Delete(Result, Length(Result), 1);
end;
```

and call it like this:

```
  Caption := GetSelectedCheckboxValue(CheckListBox1);
```

Or if you want the result in an Array :

```
function GetSelectedCheckboxValue_Take2(CheckListBox: TCheckListBox): TStringDynArray;
var
  i: Integer;
  ResultArray: TStringDynArray;
begin
  ResultArray := nil;
  for i := 0 to CheckListBox.Count - 1 do
    if CheckListBox.Checked[i] then
    begin
      SetLength(ResultArray, Length(ResultArray) + 1);
      ResultArray[Length(ResultArray) - 1] := CheckListBox.Items[i];
    end;

  Result := ResultArray;
end;
```

The last part

> And If he doesn't selects one then the default enabled checkbox value
>   needs to be selected into an array.

Makes no sense what so ever.

Comment: `... and If he doesn't selects one then the default enabled checkbox value needs to be selected into an array`. This statement is also required.

Comment: An idea to @LURD concern: If result string (or array) is empty, one could return a constant default value.

Comment: @Jens, why `TCheckListBox`? OP said, he uses `TGroupBox` (probably with `TCheckBox` inside). Iteration would be on something like this: `for i := 0 to GroupBox.ControlCount - 1 do if (GroupBox.Controls[i] is TCheckBox) and TCheckBox(GroupBox.Controls[i]).Checked then AddToResult();`

Comment: Sorry I am new to delphi, so i wasn't aware of Tchecklistbox so I thought of using groupbox (thanks Jens Borrisholt).